# How to add a static list to a list?

Tags: list, vim, nested, global-variables

When adding a global variable to a list, does vim add this variable as a dynamic list?

**input:**

```
g:ListTotal = []

let g:mylist = ['hi','2','','']
call add(g:ListTotal, g:mylist)
```

`echo g:ListTotal` --> `['hi','2','','']` => ok

Then in a script `g:mylist` is changed p.e.

```
let g:mylist[0] = 'hello'
```

`echo g:mylist` --> = `['hello','2','','']` => ok

adding again this list to g:ListTotal:
`call add(g:ListTotal, g:mylist)`

`:echo g:ListTotal` -->
**Output:**:

```
[['hello','2','',''],['hello','2','','']]
```

**Expected output**:

```
[['hi','2','',''],['hello','2','','']]
```

Does vim dynamically update lists when they're added to another list?
How can I add a list statically to another list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe list variables are just pointers to the list so adding to list just add that pointer which is why changing looks like it changes both.

If you want a unique list you can copy the list.

```
call add(g:ListTotal, copy(g:mylist))
```

Or

```
call add(g:ListTotal, deepcopy(g:my list))
```

Read `:h copy()` and `:h deepcopy()`.